# Subject not working between two unrelated components

Tags: angular, subject

I have two components, sourceComponent and targetComponent. I would like a execute a function in targetComponent on a button click event in sourceComponent. I have decided to use Subject for this.

sourceComponent.ts

```
export class SourceComponent{
    constructor(private btnclk: ButtonClickService){}
       onButtonClick(){
           this.btnclk.updateButtonClick(event);
       }
}
```

targetComponent.ts

```
export class TargetComponent{
    constructor(private btnclk: ButtonClickService){
        this.btnclk.getButtonClick().subscribe(event=>{
            console.log('Click from source component to target component') // not working
        });
    }
}
```

ButtonClickService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ButtonCLickService{
    private btnclk = new Subject<Event>();

    getButtonClick() : Observable<Event>{
        return this.btnclk.asObservable();
    }

    updateButtonClick(event : Event){
        this.btnclk.next(event);
    }
}
```

But when I subscribe to the same click event in the appComponent.ts, it is working fine.

appComponenet.ts

```
export class AppComponent{
    constructor(private btnclk: ButtonClickService){
        this.btnclk.getButtonClick().subscribe(event=>{
          console.log('Click from source component to app component') //working
        });
    }
}
```

Please explain why it works between the parent and child component and is not working between two unrelated component. Also please help me how can I make this work between two unrelated component. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share slackblitz code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdt41u

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for global service, you should provide once in root level (usually the root NgModule or using `providedIn: 'root'`) to working on same instance of the service (singleton service). from Angular docs (https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)

I have sample demo for you, it will working as you expected:

**ButtonClickService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

interface Event {
  type: string;
  data: any;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' // <= using `providedIn: 'root'` to provide at root level
})
export class ButtonClickService {

  private btnclk = new Subject<Event>();

  getButtonClick(): Observable<Event> {
    return this.btnclk.asObservable();
  }

  updateButtonClick(event: Event) {
    this.btnclk.next(event);
  }

}
```

**AppModule**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, SourceComponent, TargetComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [] // <= don't need to provide on any NgModule
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Online Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxj1ax

Answer (score 0):

You must provide your service in root to make it work globally.

Angular CLI command do it for you by default:

`ng g service ButtonClick`